# PHP: is there any way to filter "raw" input GET?

Tags: php, get

I have access to a server that runs a PHP script to parse data sent from an app to which I have no access. The data is sent through HTTP GET, and it is not sensitive data. The problem is sometimes a user inserts "illegal" characters like "#", and that totally breaks the PHP get parsing. For example: if the server receives "input.php?name=John#Doe&email=test@gmail.com", all that is parsed is name="John". The rest is lost.
My plan is to "filter out" bad characters from the input data BEFORE the GET array is parsed. I tried using $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], but got nowhere.
My question is: is it possible to use PHP to filter characters from the "raw" string data received by the server?
Thanks

Comment: No, you need to `urlencode` the data before putting it in the get string of the URL.

Comment: This is handled by the webserver, not PHP.

Comment: If this is a form use `method="POST"` that will encode data for you.

Comment: @AbraCadaver the problem is I have no access to the app that sends the data. I cannot encode the string before the data is sent.

Comment: Then there's nothing you can do (short of finding or writing your own extension for the webserver).  Certain characters have special meaning in a URL and need to be encoded before being sent to the webserver.  i.e. anything after `#` is a "fragment" and is only used by the browser and not sent to the webserver, so `Doe&email=test@gmail.com` will never be available.